# How to make time module stopwatch and tkinter run at the same time

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a stopwatch, and want to be able to show the stopwatch time on a tkinter label. When I simply tried making a label, the tkinter window just bounces, but doesn't launch. Here is the code.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

#tkinter main loop
root = tk.Tk()
#Stopwatch label
stopwatch = tk.Label(root, text="Test")
#Leading zero function
def lz(par):
    return "{:02d}".format(par)
minutes = 0
seconds = 0

#Starting the stopwatch
while True:
    print(str(lz(minutes)) + ":" + str(lz(seconds)))
    time.sleep(1)
    if seconds < 59:
        seconds += 1
    elif seconds == 59:
        seconds = 0
        minutes +=1


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have in your question this is about the simplest way to do it. It uses the universal widget [`after()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to schedule calls to the `update_stopwatch()` function every 1000 milliseconds.

Note: You shouldn't use `time.sleep()` in `tkinter` applications because it interferes with its the GUI's own event-processing `mainloop()`.

```
import tkinter as tk


# Initialize tkinter.
root = tk.Tk()

# Stopwatch label
stopwatch = tk.Label(root, text="Test")
stopwatch.pack()

minutes = 0
seconds = 0

def update_stopwatch():
    global minutes
    global seconds

    if seconds < 59:
        seconds += 1
    elif seconds == 59:
        seconds = 0
        minutes +=1

    # Update Label.
    time_string = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(minutes, seconds)
    stopwatch.config(text=time_string)

    root.after(1000, update_stopwatch)  # Call again in 1000 millisecs.


update_stopwatch()  # Start stopwatch updating.
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

look an OO approach for a basic stopwatch ;)

when open set a time and press Start button.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import threading
import queue
import time
from playsound import playsound
import winsound
import platform


class StopWatch(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue,h, m, s, stopwatch):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)


        self.queue = queue
        self.check = True
        self.h = h.get()
        self.m = m.get()
        self.s = s.get()
        self.t = (h.get() * 3600 + m.get() * 60 + s.get())
        self.stopwatch = stopwatch
        self.is_play = None

    def stop(self):
        flags = winsound.SND_FILENAME
        winsound.PlaySound(None, flags)
        self.check = False


    def play_sound(self, sound_file,):

        try:
            # Windows
            if platform.system() == 'Windows':
                flags = winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_LOOP
                winsound.PlaySound(sound_file, flags)
            # Linux
            elif platform.system() == "Linux":
                os.system("aplay -q {}&".format(sound_file))
        except:
            messagebox.showwarning(self.parent.title(), "Time over.", parent=self)


    def run(self):

        for i in range(0,self.t):

            if i == (self.t-1):
                file=os.path.join('sounds', "alarm.wav")
                self.play_sound(file)


            if not self.check:
                self.is_play=None

                break

            if self.s !=0:
                self.s -= 1
            else:
                self.s = 59
                if self.m !=0:
                    self.m -=1
                else:
                    if self.h !=0:
                        self.h -=1
                        self.m = 59

            clock = (self.h, self.m, self.s)
            self.queue.put(clock)
            time.sleep(1)

        self.check = False


class Main(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.clock = None

        self.h =  tk.IntVar()
        self.m =  tk.IntVar()
        self.s =  tk.IntVar()

        self.vcmd = (self.register(self.validate), '%d', '%P', '%S')

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        f = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Label(f, text = "Stopwach").pack()

        w = tk.LabelFrame(f, borderwidth=1)

        d = tk.Spinbox(w, bg='white', fg='blue',width=2, from_=0, to=24,
                       validate = 'key',
                       validatecommand = self.vcmd,
                       textvariable=self.h,relief=tk.GROOVE,)

        m = tk.Spinbox(w, bg='white',fg='blue', width=2, from_=0, to=60,
                       validate = 'key',
                       validatecommand = self.vcmd,
                       textvariable=self.m,relief=tk.GROOVE,)

        y = tk.Spinbox(w, bg='white', fg='blue',width=4, from_=0, to=60,
                       validate = 'key',
                       validatecommand = self.vcmd,
                       textvariable=self.s,relief=tk.GROOVE,)

        for p,i in enumerate((d,m,y)):
            i.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, padx=2)

        w.pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)

        w = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Button(w, text="Start", command=self.on_start).pack()
        ttk.Button(w, text="Stop", command=self.on_stop).pack()
        ttk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def on_start(self, evt=None):

        try:
            self.clock = StopWatch(self.queue,self.h,self.m,self.s,self)
            self.clock.start()
            self.periodic_call()

        except :
            msg = "Format error:\n%s"%str(sys.exc_info()[1])
            messagebox.showerror(self.parent.title(), msg, parent=self)



    def on_stop(self,evt=None):
        self.clock.stop()

    def on_close(self, evt=None):
        self.clock.stop()
        self.parent.on_exit()

    def periodic_call(self):

        self.check_queue()
        if self.clock.is_alive():
            self.after(1, self.periodic_call)
        else:
            pass

    def check_queue(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                x = self.queue.get(0)
                self.h.set(x[0])
                self.m.set(x[1])
                self.s.set(x[2])

            except queue.Empty:
                pass

    def validate(self, action, value, text,):
        # action=1 -> insert
        if(action=='1'):
            if text in '0123456789':
                try:
                    int(value)
                    return True
                except ValueError:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True              

class App(tk.Tk):
    """Start here"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)

        self.set_title()
        self.set_style()

        frame = Main(self,)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def set_style(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        #('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
        self.style.theme_use("clam")


    def set_title(self):
        s = "{0}".format('Simple App')
        self.title(s)

    def on_exit(self):
        """Close all"""
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Simple App", "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Threading is adding a huge amount of needless complexity. Threads are definitely not needed for a simple stopwatch.

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

#tkinter main loop
root = tk.Tk()
#Stopwatch label
stopwatch = tk.Label(root, text="The time is displayed here")
#to make the stopwatch occupy the whole window 
stopwatch.pack() 
#Leading zero function
def lz(par):
    return "{:02d}".format(par)
minutes = 0
seconds = 0

#Starting the stopwatch
def stop_watch() :
    global minutes, seconds 
    while True:
        count = str(lz(minutes)) + ":" + str(lz(seconds))
        stopwatch.after(1000, count) 
        if seconds < 59:
            seconds += 1
        elif seconds == 59:
            seconds = 0
            minutes +=1


root.mainloop()
```

The after function makes the label update after 1 second and execute the code below it.

Comment: How do I make the stopwatch display the count?

Comment: Did you execute the code? The code updates the stopwatch every second.

Comment: Did _you_ run the code? This code doesn't and can't work.